# Vertically/ horizontally closest boxes R-Tree

Tags: python, spatial-index, r-tree

I am experimenting with [R-tree](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Rtree/) package in python. While there's a way to do nearest neighbor search, is there a way to produce the K nearest neighbors based on vertical/ horizontal distance separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create two additional data-sets, "projecting" points into each axis by removing the other coordinate. Then, you'll have transformed the problem into a 1-dimensional nearest-neighbour search.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the Python APIs. In a good API, you should be able to implement custom distance functions, that e.g. only select neighbors along one axis.
Somehow, I expect the Python part to be simply a wrapper around C code, and then you would probably need to go into C to extend this functionality...

This does not require a separate tree to be built.